# Uneditable JTextField with cursor selection enabled

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Is it possible to keep the JTextField uneditable, but keep the selection option using cursor enabled?

Comment: Please don't add sigs. or noise like 'Thanks' to questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set editable to false via `setEditable(...)` The default for the focusable property is true so there will be no need to call `setFocusable(...)`.

Comment: Correct. This indeed allows you to still select it and even copy the selected values.